# Random rect generation generating all rects next to each other

Tags: javascript, canvas, random, html5-canvas

I'm working on random rectangle generation for a game in canvas, and I added some code to prevent the randomly generated rectangles from overlapping, however rather than preventing my rectangles from overlapping, it's like it makes it so it has to overlap or else it wont place it. here is my code (I know it's messy and unoptimized)

```
function random_place(){
var x,y,height,width
x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);
y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
width = Math.floor(Math.random() * (85 - 20 + 1) + 20);
height = Math.floor(Math.random() * (85 - 20 + 1) + 20);
return([x,y,width,height])
}



function generate_obstacles(obstacles_count){
var counter = 0
var placement
var placement_colide = false;
console.log(obstacle_array.length)
while(counter < obstacles_count){
placement_colide = false;
x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);
y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);
width = Math.floor(Math.random() * 85);
height = Math.floor(Math.random() * 60);
placement = random_place();
for(let i=0; i<obstacle_array.length; i++){
if(obstacle_array[i][0]+100 > placement[0]+(placement[2]/2)+100 || obstacle_array[i][0]+(obstacle_array[i][2]/2)+40 < placement[0]) {
if(obstacle_array[i][1]+35 > placement[1]+(placement[3]/2)+35 || obstacle_array[i][1]+(obstacle_array[i][3]/2)+35 < placement[1]){placement_colide = true; break}
}
placement_colide = true; break
}
if((placement[0] > (player_x*2)+5 || placement[0] < (player_x/2)+1.5) && placement_colide == true){
obstacle_array.push(placement);
counter++;
i = obstacle_array.length
}
}
```

I also have the full code in jsfiddle if that would be easier to read
https://jsfiddle.net/Fightingox/1dk0oaty/54/

anyone know the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Messy code is buggy code

I could not work out what you have done wrong because the code is a mess.

Names are way to long. You set properties as array indexes rather than by named properties. And more..

Rather than fix your code I have re-written creating some functions and renaming many objects.

### Rewrite in parts

To create a random rectangle

```
const randI = range => Math.random() * range | 0; // only for positive ints
function randomGameRect() {
    const x = randI(10000);
    const y = randI(100);
    const w = randI(61) + 20;
    const h = randI(61) + 20;
    return {x, y, w, h};
}
```

To check if two rectangles overlap.

```
function doRectsOverlay(rectA, rectB) {
    return !(                           // Overlaps if not any of...
        rectA.x > rectB.x + rectB.w ||  // left of rectA right of right of rectB
        rectB.x > rectA.x + rectA.w ||  // right of rectA left of left of rectB
        rectA.y > rectB.y + rectB.h ||  // top of rectA below bottom of rectB
        rectB.y > rectA.y + rectA.h);   // bottom of rectA above top of rectB
}
```

To add a rectangle `rect` to an array of rectangles `rects` if there is no overlap.

Note I also added the player check you do. I am not sure why you do it so I just put it in.

```
function addIfNotOverlap(rect, rects) {
    if (!rects.some(r => doRectsOverlay(r, rect)) {
        
        // check player stuff. I don't know why you do this.
        if (place.x > (player_x * 2) + 5 || place.x < (player_x / 2) + 1.5) {
            rects.push(rect);
        }
    }    
}
```

And the last function replaces yours. It adds `count` rectangles to the array of rectangles `obstacleArray`. This function requires all the functions above

```
function generateObstacles(count) {
    while (count-- > 0) {
        addIfNotOverlap(randomGameRect(), obstacleArray);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, works great